# Fail to decode JSON with swift Combine

Tags: json, swift, network-programming, combine

I'm trying to read this JSON data with Combine but I cannot make it work if I try to read the **release** field.
The address https://amiiboapi.com/api/ returns something like this:

```
{
"amiibo": [
    {
      "amiiboSeries": "Super Smash Bros.", 
      "character": "Mario", 
      "gameSeries": "Super Mario", 
      "head": "00000000", 
      "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/N3evin/AmiiboAPI/master/images/icon_00000000-00000002.png", 
      "name": "Mario", 
      "release": {
        "au": "2014-11-29", 
        "eu": "2014-11-28", 
        "jp": "2014-12-06", 
        "na": "2014-11-21"
      }, 
      "tail": "00000002", 
      "type": "Figure"
    }, 
    {
      "amiiboSeries": "Super Mario Bros.", 
      "character": "Mario", 
      "gameSeries": "Super Mario", 
      "head": "00000000", 
      "image": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/N3evin/AmiiboAPI/master/images/icon_00000000-00340102.png", 
      "name": "Mario", 
      "release": {
        "au": "2015-03-21", 
        "eu": "2015-03-20", 
        "jp": "2015-03-12", 
        "na": "2015-03-20"
      }, 
      "tail": "00340102", 
      "type": "Figure"
    } 
  ] 
}
```

I have my model like this:

```
// MARK: - Amiibo List
struct AmiibosList: Codable {
    let amiibo: [Amiibo]
}

 // MARK: - Amiibo
struct Amiibo: Codable {
    let amiiboSeries: String
    let character: String
    let gameSeries: String
    let head: String
    let image: String
    let name: String
    let release: Release
    let tail: String
    let type: String
}

// MARK: - Release
struct Release: Codable  {
    let au : String?
    let eu : String?
    let jp : String?
    let na : String?
}
```

And I'm trying to fetch the data like this:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://amiiboapi.com/api/") else {
    fatalError("Invalid URL")
}

var publisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .map(\.data)
    .decode(type: AmiiboList.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        if case .failure(let err) = completion {
            print("Failed with error \(err)")
        }
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print("Received \(value)")
        //        print(" Received \(value.amiibo[0].release)")
    })
```

If I comment/remove the release from my amiibo struct, everything works. For some reason I cannot retrieve the data with the release dates and I can't figure why.
Do I need to do anything else for nested JSON data?

Comment: From the json provided it seems that amibo is the actual struct, not an array. Simply changing `[Amibo]` to `Amibo` resolved the issue for me

Comment: Didn't notice that. Makes sense thanks. But even after the change It only works if I don't put the release field. Still not able to get the data with it. Thanks for noticing that though

Comment: What I did to make this work is to declare the `release` field as `[String: Date]` dictionary. Note that to make this work, you can't simply use a simple `JsonDecoder`. You will have to modify the `dateEncodingStrategy` so that it parses your date format

Comment: "I'm trying to read this JSON data with Combine" - Combine and Codable are two separate concepts, try to figure out which one is failing for you, otherwise the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

With the below, you can simply do: `response.amiibo[0].release` to get the release object. Note that the release object contains Date objects rather than Strings. That should be helpful.

```
func example(data: Data) throws -> Response {
    let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
    return try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let amiibo: [Amiibo]
}

struct Amiibo: Codable {
    let amiiboSeries: String
    let character: String
    let gameSeries: String
    let head: String
    let image: URL?
    let name: String
    let release: Release
    let tail: String
    let type: String
}

struct Release: Codable {
    let au: Date?
    let eu: Date?
    let jp: Date?
    let na: Date?
}
```